# How to make only certain Error Messages appear in the Validation Summary (MVC3)

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, validation, razor

In MVC 3 razor there appears to be 2 options:

Show all the errors of the various properties in the Validation Summary

```
@Html.ValidationSummary(false)
```

or show the errors next to the properties themselves

```
@Html.ValidationSummary(true)
```

But I would like only *some* of the properties to display their error in the Validation Summary, (Error messages returned from my Validate override, eg)

```
    public IEnumerable<ValidationResult> Validate(ValidationContext context)
    {
        if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(HomePhoneNumber) && string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(WorkPhoneNumber) && string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(MobileNumber) && string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(FaxNumber))
        {
            yield return new ValidationResult("Please fill in at least one of the phone fields with a phone number");
        }
    }
```

and other, more simple validation to have their error message displayed next to them, as defined by the model, eg

```
 [Required(ErrorMessage = "Please fill in your full name")]
```

Is this possible?

Answer (score 0):

It is possible.
 `ValidationSummary()` displays ModelErrors for `string.empty` as the key.
Here is sample code:

```cs
IList<ValidationResult> validationResults = Validate();

if (validationResults != null) {
    foreach (var validationResult in validationResults) {
        ModelState.AddModelError(String.Empty, validationResult.ErrorMessage);
    }
}
```

In view:

```
@Html.ValidationSummary(true)
```

**Edit:**

Above is a sample example of how the ValidationSummery helper treats non-property (object) level messages.

However, your code should work as you expected, consider that the validation interface method `IEnumerable<ValidationResult> IValidatableObject.Validate(ValidationContext validationContext)` is triggered if there are no errors in the properties of the object. Here is default sequence of validation checking:

- Property attributes
- Class attributes
- Validate interface

If any of the step failed, it will return immediately without further checking.
If unobtrusive client validation is enable, the attributes based validations should be fired at the client end. Then the validation interface would fired during model binding.

Comment: and secondly: shouldn't Validate be invoked with the ValidationContext parameter? given that the interface needs to be implemented so.

Comment: Yes, normally in the controller.

Comment: sorry, I was focusing on the ValidationSummery helper, how it treats non-property (object) level messages. I have updated the answer.

Comment: sorry I am still really struggling to get this working, because it MUST pass the ValidationContext, and I'm not really sure how to do this.

Comment: I keep getting "Cannot resolve symbol 'Validate'" - wherever I put it in the controller. I have also tried accessing the validationResults list in the model (as I have overridden the Validate method) but I can't get that working either. The code seems to work...I'm just unable to populate validationResults

Comment: Would you please add more details about your model, controller action, view in your question?

Comment: What details do you need? I have shown the important bit of the model in the question and the controller could be empty for all intents and purposes.